# Connect Xaxis of a chart to another one

Tags: vb.net

I have an application made of a "main" chart with stock quotes plotted in it and a "subordinated" one with some indicators; the two charts are dinamically feeded with data so they are ever moving and re-sizing their own YAxis accordingly. The following snapshot gives a better idea:

[image]

What I would like to do is to make the below chart XAxis exactly the same of the first one, so that it is possible to follow the evolution of the two indicators together.

Right now I'm doing the following work around:

```
With ChartBelow.ChartAreas(0)
.AxisX.Minimum = ChartAbove.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum
.AxisX.Maximum = ChartAbove.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum
End With
```

However this doesn't work well since the digits of the YAxis on the main chart are not always the same of the second one (as in the example above where it's 6-digits against 3-only).

Is there any way to aligne the two y-axes or make the X-Axis shared between the two charts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as well as setting the Min/Max values, also set the interval and label interval values of the Axis.

ChartAbove.ChartAreas(0).XAxis.Interval

ChartAbove.ChartAreas(0).XAxis.LabelStyle.Interval

Comment: I didn't get you.. You mean `.AxisX.Interval = ChartAbove.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval()`?